# Java JPA sequence ID as String

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is what I currently have, which works fine

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="EDGE_DEAL_BOOKING_EDGEDEALNUMBER_GENERATOR", sequenceName="EDGEDEALNUM_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EDGE_DEAL_BOOKING_EDGEDEALNUMBER_GENERATOR")
private int edgedealnumber;

public int getEdgedealnumber() {
    return this.edgedealnumber;
}

public void setEdgedealnumber(int edgedealnumber) {
    this.edgedealnumber = edgedealnumber;
}
```

However, for the ID I need it to be a string with a string prefix, ie. EDGE12345.  I tried to switch the code to :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="EDGE_DEAL_BOOKING_EDGEDEALNUMBER_GENERATOR", sequenceName="EDGEDEALNUM_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EDGE_DEAL_BOOKING_EDGEDEALNUMBER_GENERATOR")
private String edgedealnumber;

public String getEdgedealnumber() {
    return this.edgedealnumber;
}

public void setEdgedealnumber(String edgedealnumber) {
    this.edgedealnumber = "EDG"+edgedealnumber;
}
```

but it gives

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String
```

Comment: maybe http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/ ?

Comment: the @GenericGenerator annotation doesn't exist... options are auto, identity, sequence, table, none - im using JPA

Comment: [GenericGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) seems to be a Hibernate annotation, not a generic JPA one.  Do you need to stay with generic JPA, or can you use something Hibernate-specific?

Comment: after 2-3 hours of researching and trying many ways of overriding/ editing the object after it persists ive come to the conclusion its impossible and the easiest way is to make a new dummy JPA ID column then inserting what i want in the read ID column.  thanks guys